# How to handle huge sales_flat_quote tables - remove abandoned cart refuse

Tags: mysql, log, maintenance

**Situation**

In our magento database we have three tables that are growing too big.

1. sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate: 3045MB
2. sales_flat_quote_address: 1688MB
3. sales_flat_quote: 1897MB

That's more than 6GB of data.

I've found this article on [how to truncate these tables](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/enourmous-magento-sales_flat_quote-tables/). This article only speaks of the third table.

I'm not sure about the truncating, and I prefer to delete all data older than 60 days. The article speaks of 17 million records - we have 20! If I'm correct, deleting these records won't lock the table, and I'm currently testing this on a test installation. That seems to work, and it doesn't conflict too much with the site.

**Questions**

- I would like to know if I can use the same query for the other two tables as well?
- I'm wondering what these tables are for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE updated_at < DATE_SUB(Now(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)
```

`sales_flat_quote` and it's related tables use foreign key relations to delete on cascade so deletions in the primary table deletes all related entries automatically in the other tables.

Once you get it down in size, you can easily modify the observer (obligatory make a module here) that's supposed to clean out expired quotes to include all quotes as is done in the first link with customized retention for abandoned cart recovery and retention of logged in customer quotes for a reasonable period so your customers don't get mad when their cart empties unexpectedly: [Are unconverted quote records ever removed in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545128/are-unconverted-quote-records-ever-removed-in-magento/24898705#24898705)

or use Fabrizio Branca's [AOE Quote Cleaner](https://github.com/fbrnc/Aoe_QuoteCleaner)

sales_flat_quote* tables contain shopping cart contents. This is known as a quote and is held until the customer decides to finish placing the order. For finished quotes that have been converted to Sales-Order, Magento automatically clears them with a cron job. The logic was never extended to include open quotes.

Comment: I see that the size of the other table decreases, so the cascading works. I'm going to test the AOE module. That's a good tip!

Comment: I ran that script many times, with `limit 1000000`, until all records older than 60 days were gone. Then I installed the AOE Quote Cleaner module. I didn't use the AOE module for the 20m deletes, as the website stopped working - on the test machine at least. The script didn't pose any problems.

Comment: You're welcome! I had to tackle the problem way back before Fabrizio's module became available and so went the observer route after doing something similar to your cleanup. It took about 20 passes to clear the gunk. Now that it's on scheduled cleanup, no worries!

Comment: I want to delete some records which customer doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Although Fiasco Labs's solution works, I would just start off with an extension right from the get-go and use `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Resource_Collection` to filter and remove older quotes of choosing. Using the proper methods, you can ensure your operation will work on any Magento installation by not relying on database constraints or raw queries.

Something like (untested)…

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->getCollection() 
    -->addFieldToSelect('entity_id') // this is important
    -->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('lt' => 'some_date'));

foreach ($collection as $quote) {
    $quote->delete(); // safely delete selected quote
}
```

You could extend this off of `Mage_Log` or make its own stand-alone extension. Pretty simple.

Comment: Why would I want to create my own module when AOE has a working module ready for download?

Comment: The AOE extensions are great, so I'm not discrediting those at all. But to give you reasons.. `1.` Avoid using manual queries in extensions. `2.` Try to make you extensions independent, if possible. `DELETE` queries like these depend on the database constraint, which may be altered in the future. `3.` Use Magento factory methods appropriately.

Comment: Seems like that one was made a while ago @musicliftsme.. usually they're pretty good

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT quote_id FROM sales_flat_order);
```

This query will delete all quotes, that where not converted in orders.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2, the ‘sales_flat_quote’ was replaced with ‘quote’, so following SQL command can fix this issue for Magento2:

```
update quote set items_count = NULL
```

Comment: Kind of, mixing with @fiasco's answer: `DELETE FROM quote WHERE updated_at < DATE_SUB(Now(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

A client's database that had over 500K records in this table was causing a serious slowdown. Here was my approach.

## Make backups!

#### No, seriously. Make backups using `mysqldump`.

## Here's What I Did - After Making A Backup

**1. Find the tables that reference `sales_flat_quote`.**

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'sales_flat_quote' AND REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'entity_id' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '[your-magento-db-name]';
```

This is why this step was so important:

```
+--------------------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME               | COLUMN_NAME |
+--------------------------+-------------+
| sales_flat_quote_address | quote_id    |
| sales_flat_quote_item    | quote_id    |
| sales_flat_quote_payment | quote_id    |
| task_system              | quote_id    |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

There might be extensions that also reference it. And in my client's case, there was! Furthermore, it was a cascade FK. If we had deleted that, it would have deleted all the records in their `task_system` table.

We updated the `task_system`.`quote_id` to `DEFAULT NULL` and then the FK to `ON DELETE SET_NULL`.

Now we're safe to do this:

**2. Delete all carts/quotes over 60 days old:**

Kudos to: Fiasco Labs

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE updated_at < DATE_SUB(Now(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) LIMIT 100;
COMMIT;
```

*OR*, try this if you want to keep quotes referenced by the `sales_flat_order` table:

Kudos to: Fiasco Labs and Styopchik

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM sales_flat_quote WHERE entity_id NOT IN (SELECT quote_id FROM sales_flat_order) AND `updated_at` < DATE_SUB(Now(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) LIMIT 100;
COMMIT;
```

**Note:** The `LIMIT 100` here as this could completely lock up your database. Do it in batches.

**2. Don't Assume!**

Do not assume all is well.

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sales_flat_quote_item;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       21 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

So we have some orphaned data. You need to get rid of that by JOINING the `sales_flat_quote_` tables to the `sales_flat_quote` table where quote_id IS NULL. That's out of scope for this answer. just Google "deleting mysql orphaned records". Make backups!