# What is use of sales_flat_quote table? Can it be truncated?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, quote

I want to know functionality of `sales_flat_quote` table. If I would truncate this table then will any issue occur or not?

Comment: If you truncate it any customers currently using your website will lose their cart data.

Comment: Unless you truncate quotes which aren't active. Anyways, quote represent your cart, which is then transformed into an order after payment.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36694/how-to-handle-huge-sales-flat-quote-tables-remove-abandoned-cart-refuse

Answer (score 0):

It carries the current quote data of the customer. You can truncate it. But you will loose currently added products in the cart of the customer.